# Jquery slider with autoplay and navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm trying to build a small slider in jquery, that autoplays and also has navigation buttons that allow to change the current slide. So far I managed to get the Buttons to work, but as I'm not very confident with JQuery I have no idea how to get the timed change to work.

I tried some suggestions I saw here on stackoverflow, like using setInterval and setTimeout, but I can not get it to work properly. My main problem is that I want to make sure the animations finish before the slide is changed per click and that a click resets the timer for the autoplay.

I hope someone here can help me with my problem.

Edit: I got a timer function to work, now my problem is that if you click a button while the animation is running, it might result in two slides being shown at the same time. How can I make sure the click is qued until the animations have finished playing?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9sgfd22r/10/

Here is my function:

```
 (function($){
        $.fn.Slider = function(interval) {

            var slides = $sliderdiv.children('.slides');
            var amount = slides.length;
            var i = 0;
            var animation = 0;
            var clicked = 0;

            function run() {
                animation = 1;
                $('.slides:visible').each(function() {
                    active = this.id.replace('slide', '');
                    active = active - 1;
                    console.log(active);
                });

                $(slides[active]).fadeOut(1000, function(){
                    i = clicked - 1;

                    $("img", $(slides[i])).each(function(){
                        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
                    });

                    $(slides[i]).fadeIn(1000);
                    clicked = 0;
                    animation = 0;
                    intervaltint = setInterval(autoplay,3000);
                });
            }



            function autoplay(){
                console.log('running');
                animation = 1;
                $('.slides:visible').each(function() {
                    active2 = this.id.replace('slide', '');
                    active2 = active2 - 1;
                    console.log(active2);
                });

                $(slides[active2]).fadeOut(1000, function(){
                    active2++;
                    if (active2 >= amount) active2 = 0;

                    $("img", $(slides[active2])).each(function(){
                        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
                    });

                    $(slides[active2]).fadeIn(1000);
                    animation = 0;
                });
            }

            intervaltint = setInterval(autoplay,3000);

            var $slidernav = $('.slidernav');
            $('.slidernav').click(function() {

                clearInterval(intervaltint);

                activeslide = this.id.replace('slidernav', '');

                if (animation == 0) {
                    clicked = activeslide;
                    run();
                }
                else {
                    console.log('not now');

                    clicked = activeslide;
                    run();
                }
            });

        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: create a  fiddle and share with us

Comment: I added the fiddle, yet as silly as this may sound, I can't even get my script to work in the fiddle. What do I have to change for it to work? Edit: got it to work!

Comment: I changed the fiddle based on what I managed so far, I would still need help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/9sgfd22r/11/)

Sample code which i have added is

```
function next(){
    if (animation == 0) {
        $('.slides').each(function(index,value) {
            if($(this).is(':visible')){
                if(($('.slides').length-1) == index){
                    clicked = 1;
                }
                else{
                    if(clicked == 0)
                        clicked++;
                    clicked++;
                }
            }
        });
        run();
    }
}

$('#next').click(function(){
    next();
});
```

Comment: Can you explain your code to me? Especially this line `$('.slides').each(function(index,value)` , I don't quite understand what index and value are used for in your function. Thank you a lot.

Comment: i am passing an anonymous function to method `each` which takes two parameters one is the index the other one is actual element (value). for more info please read [this](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Alright I see. But if I'm not mistaken, your function does also not handle the problem of pressing the 'next' element while the animation is still playing. How can I 'queue up' the clicks on the element? So that pressing the next-element twice fast actually advances two slides after another?

Comment: as of now it is not. i will just nullify the events which are created, untill the animation is complete. if you want to queue then you have to manually do that by building a queue mechanism. also is that what you asked initially?

Comment: Would buidling a queue machanism be complicated? As I said I don't have much experience with Jquery and JS yet. It's not what I asked for initially but after I updated with what I managed to get so far. But I could either ignore all clicks until the animation is done or have the bug I mentioned in my question. Initially I was asking for help with a timer function, which I managed to get working on my own later. I'm sorry if my question is very confusing and of bad grammar, English isn't my first language and I'm not that good at it. So I want to apologize sincerly if you misunderstood me.